# sphinx文章内の置換について、txtをincludeした場合の文字列処理

Tags: python, python3, sphinx

みなさん初めまして、どうぞ宜しくお願いいたします。

早速ですが、ある構造計算プログラムをpythonで作成しその結果を、exp.txtで書き出しています。書き出した中身は以下の様な内容です。
　　　　`.. |t1| replace:: 100`
　　　　`.. |t2| replace:: ok`

これを、ひな型としてsphinxであらかじめ作成しておいたrst内の先頭行で
    `.. include:: exp.txt`
で読込んで `|t1|`で置換はできるのですが、txt内の　`.. |t3| replace:: あいう` といった文字列である場合、置換が行われません。
英数字の場合でしか置換ができませんでしょうか？

`.. literalinclude:: exp.txt` も試しましたがうまくいきませんでした。

出力側の文字コードの問題なのかそれとも他に記法があるのか教授下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exp.txt の文字コードが Shift_JIS となっているのではないでしょうか？
Shift_JISのファイルを include すると次のようにエラーが出てファイルが読み込まれません。

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 61: invalid start byte
/Users/set0gut1/tmp/stackoverflow/index.rst:15: WARNING: Undefined substitution referenced: "t1".
/Users/set0gut1/tmp/stackoverflow/index.rst:15: WARNING: Undefined substitution referenced: "t2".
/Users/set0gut1/tmp/stackoverflow/index.rst:15: WARNING: Undefined substitution referenced: "t3".
```

この場合は exp.txt を UTF-8 に変換すると解決します（`nkf`が便利です）。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ご指摘の通り文字コードが`Shift_JIS`となっていたようです。
python側で`txt`の書き出しの際に、`utf-8`エンコードを追記することで、無事にincludeできました。
python3である場合、`utf-8`で書き出されるものと思い込んでおりました。
ありがとうございました。